# Access to StandardInput from NRECO.VideoConverter?

Tags: c#, nreco

I'm currently using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658415/how-to-use-pipe-in-ffmpeg-within-c-sharp) to pipe a string of bitmaps into ffmpeg.  It requires redirecting StandardInput stream and writing to it.

Is something similar available with NRECO.VideoConverter?  Is there a way to get either access to the running process, or access to just the StandardInput base stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to provide input data to stdin or read output data from stdout (or both) you may use [`ConvertLiveMedia`](https://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.VideoConverter/?topic=html/Overload_NReco_VideoConverter_FFMpegConverter_ConvertLiveMedia.htm) method; it has overloads for different usage scenarios:

```
var videoConv = new FFMpegConverter();          
var ffMpegTask = videoConv.ConvertLiveMedia(
    "rawvideo",
    h264stream, 
    "h264",
    new ConvertSettings() {
        CustomInputArgs = String.Format(" -pix_fmt bgr24 -video_size 640x480 -framerate 5 ", 
            frameBmp.Width, frameBmp.Height)
    });
ffMpegTask.Start();
ffMpegTask.Write( bmpBytes );  // call N times for each input frame. Image size should be exactly 640x480
ffMpegTask.Stop();
```

You can adopt this code snippet for "image2pipe" if needed.