# How to encode video with ffmpeg form videocapture Mat

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv, ffmpeg

I'm trying to make video editor tool.

[Environment]
C#
WPF
OpenCVSharp4.5

When encoding video,I have to set some config.(fps/width/height/codec/bitrate/field-order)
But,can't set field-order with opencv's videowriter.

```
        VideoWriter video = new VideoWriter(
            outPutFilePath,
            VideoCaptureAPIs.FFMPEG,
            VideoWriter.FourCC(Char.Parse("M"),
            Char.Parse("P"),
            Char.Parse("4"),
            Char.Parse("V"),
            fps,
            new OpenCvSharp.Size(Width, Height),
            true);
            for (int movePos = StartFrame; movePos < EndFrame; movePos++)
            {
                PosFrames = movePos;
                Mat mat = SetMatFromFrameNo(PosFrames);

                video.Write(mat);
               Cv2.WaitKey(1);
            }
```

so,I'm trying to use piped ffmpeg.
But I have no idea.

Could you tell how to encode video From VideoCaptures. thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658415/how-to-use-pipe-in-ffmpeg-within-c-sharp

I refered this to encode with piped ffmpeg. but cant...

Comment: I solved it with runnning ffmpeg from Process  backgroud